# How remove path from url

Tags: magento-2.1

Can somebody tell me how can i remove category-id and view-id path to my products url? 
I drag and drop categories to new and this proplem started.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below configurations in your store.

> Stores > Configurations > Catalog > Catalog > Storefront > Search Engine Optimization > Use Categories Path for Product URLs > YES/NO

don't forget to Reindexing and flush the cache

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! Can you tell me how reindex in magento admin? Or where should i go/write this? php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: you have to use CLI for it.  Command Line

Comment: Is there any way to do it on backend?